# Using Pandas GroupBy and size()/count() to generate an aggregated DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

So I currently have a DataFrame called `df` that goes:

```
date                       tag
2011-02-18 12:57:00-07:00  A
2011-02-19 12:57:00-07:00  A
2011-03-18 12:57:00-07:00  B
2011-04-01 12:57:00-07:00  C
2011-05-19 12:57:00-07:00  Z
2011-06-03 12:57:00-07:00  A
2011-06-05 12:57:00-07:00  A
...
```

I'm trying to do a GroupBy the tag, and the date (yr/month), so it looks like:

```
date     A  B  C  Z
2011-02  2  0  0  0
2011-03  0  1  0  0
2011-04  0  0  1  0
2011-05  0  0  0  1
2011-06  2  0  0  0
...
```

I've tried the following, but it doesn't quite give me what I want.

```
grouped_series = df.groupby([["%s-%s" % (d.year, d.month) for d in df.date], df.tag]).size()
```

I know which tag exists etc. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE (for people looking in the future):**

Ended up keeping the datetime, instead of string format. Trust me, this will be better when plotting:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby([[ datetime.datetime(d.year, d.month, 1, 0, 0) for d in df.date], df.name]).size()
grouped_df = grouped_df.unstack().fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use [`unstack()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`fillna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) methods:

```
>>> g = df.groupby([["%s-%s" % (d.year, d.month) for d in df.date], df.tag]).size()
>>> g
        tag
2011-2  A      2
2011-3  B      1
2011-4  C      1
2011-5  Z      1
2011-6  A      2
dtype: int64
>>> g.unstack().fillna(0)
tag     A  B  C  Z
2011-2  2  0  0  0
2011-3  0  1  0  0
2011-4  0  0  1  0
2011-5  0  0  0  1
2011-6  2  0  0  0
```