# Pandas evaluate counts of multiple values in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, count, group-by, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame df like this:

```
    Language  Id  GridCode
0         es   1         1
1         en   2        11
2         es   3         2
3         it   4         6
4         it   5        10
5         pl   6        10
6         es   7         9
7         fr   8        11
8         es   9        11
9         en  10        12
10        es  11         1
```

Basically, an "Id" is associated both to a "GridCode" and to a "Language" (a unique "Id" can be assigned to one and only one "Gridcode" but, obviously, a GridCode can be associated to more "Id"s). I'm trying to get a new DataFrame counting the frequencies of "Id" in a specific "Language" per "Gridcode", with the following columns:

```
GridCount    Count_Id_es    Count_Id_en    ...
```

and so on.
So far I created a set of Languages for a loop as:

```
languages = set(df['Language'])
```

Then I tried to use a groupby operation like this:

```
g = df.groupby(['GridCode','Id','Language']).size()
```

which returns:

```
GridCode  Id  Language
1         1   es          1
          11  es          1
2         3   es          1
6         4   it          1
9         7   es          1
10        5   it          1
          6   pl          1
11        2   en          1
          8   fr          1
          9   es          1
12        10  en          1
```

Now the problem is to count again the frequencies of the "Id"s in a specific language and store information on a new DataFrame as follows:

```
Gridcode    Count_Id_es    Count_Id_it     Count_Id_pl      Count_Id_fr     Count_Id_en
1           2              0               0                0               0
2           1              0               0                0               0
6           0              1               0                0               0
9           1              0               0                0               0
10          0              1               1                0               0
11          1              0               0                1               1
12          0              0               0                0               1
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Sorry just found an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242442/using-pandas-groupby-and-size-count-to-generate-an-aggregated-dataframe?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use getdummy

```
pd.get_dummies(df.Language)
```